# Screen goes white when trying to switch layout(s)

Tags: android

I am trying to get into coding for Android and I decided to try and make an app with a navigation drawer. I was quite happy with it until it came to me attempting to switch layouts.

When trying to switch to another layout, my screen just turns white and in the log it says `DrawerToggle may not show up because NavigationIcon is not visible. You may need to call actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

However, I can't seem to figure out how to call that method because in my code (see below), I don't use action bars...

**DISCLAMER:** I have a lot of functions and probably unnecessary code coming up, so please bare with it :)
Code moved, click [here](http://pastebin.com/Fgu2yssF) to view it.

Any help will be appreciated!!

**EDIT:** Ughh... So the screen going white was because the database got cleared by someone ;-;
That is now fixed, however, I still can't find the explanation as to why the navigation drawer won't work...

Comment: Why isn't the navigation drawer working? What is the issue? Linking to your code is great, but as per the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you should include the ***relevant*** code within the question: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to then do so - but also include the code in your question itself"

Comment: @Bryan I've explained the issue as best as I can and I decided to give all of my code instead of giving a little chunk that I think was broken then people asking for the rest of the code anyway.

Comment: I'm glad to see you fixed the problem. I just want to give some (hopefully) helpful advice for the future. I understand why you want to link to the entirety of the code, and it may very well help in answering the question. But many times that "little chunk" of code that *you* think is broken will give much more insight into your issue than having others look through everything. As for the explanation, describing *exactly* what the issue is, rather than that there simply *is* an issue will often help others provide better answers as well.

Comment: I will remember this for the future, @Bryan. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this myself by expanding my research (I was only looking for help with multiple layouts, not activities). Turns out, searching for multiple activities helped me more.

All I had to do was add `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` where I was setting up the drawer.